# Insert cities list inside a string-array in string.xml

Tags: android, xml, string

I'm working on app that includes 2 AutoCompleteTextView using a string-array in string.xml.
Right now I succeed in using the this method by inserting inside string.xml a string array with some items.

```
   <string-array name="cities_array">
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>    
        <item>...</item>
   </string-array>
```

The issue is that I would like to add a list of 1000 items, and I would like to know if it's optimal to pass that list and adding to each line a  pattern?

Comment: the best -> database, create ready database and load to android app. I know because I was loading +1K cities and when you have very large list, autocomplete need take much time by searching in that big list.. using db and cursor would give you the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using Place autocomplete google service, so in my case thats exactly what I needed.
For another usages (not cities, countries etc...) it's recommended to use database, thanks to deadfish suggestion.

Here's some examples I found: [this](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1342) and [this](http://a2zandroidtutorials.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/autocompletetextview-from-database.html) (using some php code).

Answer (score 0):

This's what computer was invented for. I suggest you to write a Java program which does the job. Converts the list of words into XML by adding the tags. Something like

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/path/to/file.txt")));

StringBuilder output=new StringBuilder();

String line;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
  output.append("<item>"+line+"</item>");  
}

// Write output to a file...
```

Although it would be even nicer to use some XML generator to do this.

Comment: Yes, I suggest you to write a simple Java program that converts the list of words into an XML file. And then you can include that XML file in your android project.